# Run the same process with different arguments using PM2

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, pm2

I want to run `npm start /app1` and `npm start /app2` so both of these apps run as daemons. I am logged onto an external virtual machine using SSH.

At first I tried using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) like this:

```
$ pm2 start npm -- start --prefix /app1
```

and it works for a single application, but when I do

```
$ pm2 start npm -- start --prefix /app1
$ pm2 start npm -- start --prefix /app2
```

The first app is killed (the second works). Seems that `npm` is a single process which I can't share between these 2 applications.

How can I run those 2 `npm` processes concurrently?

Comment: You might want to give them a name "pm2 start npm --name 'Your APP Name' -- start --prefix /app1"

Comment: @MikZuit Tried it, doesn't help. The second call restarts npm

Comment: they're not using same port I assume, right?

Comment: @MikZuit they use different ports. Everything works correctly when I run them on local computer on 2 different terminals

Comment: use "pm2 del npm" you might have created one with name "npm" , see "pm2 ls" output to see named instances

Comment: @MikZuit I was passing `--name` in a wrong order, this was the right solution! Thank you and please consider adding it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments you should run:

```
 pm2 start npm --name 'Your APP Name' -- start --prefix /app1
```

respect the order of options.

Also in order to see your active intances use "npm ls" so might not have an accidentally created an "npm" app. if so, use "pm2 del npm" to delete it.